# How to change the caption of a label using DLookup from pressing a button in Microsoft Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, button, vba, label

In Microsoft access I want to be able to change the caption of a label after pressing a certain button on my form in Microsoft Access. I have tried the VBA code as shown below but it does not work and the caption stays the same.

**How do I fix this ?**

The field from the table is an integer called "Sem1-Credits" and the contents of this field according to the relevant programmeID is what I want the label caption to be changed to.
For example the ProgrammeID of "AM" has the Sem1-Credits of "30" in the table

The Table is called "Programme"
The unique identifier of that table is "ProgrammeID"
The name of the button is AMButton

```
Forms!StudentOptionForm!S1CreditsL.Caption = DLookup("[Sem1-Credits]", "Programme", "[ProgrammeID]= '" & AMButton & "'")
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider debugging your dlookup. How does the `WHERE` condition in argument 3 evaluate? In the immediate window, what does `?AMButton` return? It returns a NULL, because command buttons do not have a `.value` property. So your argument evaluates to: `[ProgrammeID] = Null` and since ProgrammeID is your PK, there will never be a null ProgrammeID so your `DLookup` can never return a value. You need to reference your form control that contains the value of ProgrammeID, not your command button.

Answer (score 0):

You *ProgrammedID* could (and should) be a *Long*. If so, no quotes:

```
Forms!StudentOptionForm!S1CreditsL.Caption = DLookup("[Sem1-Credits]", "Programme", "[ProgrammeID] = " & AMButton & "")
```

And bevare that *DLookup* will return *Null* for no results which *Caption* doesn't accept, thus wrap in *Nz*:

```
Forms!StudentOptionForm!S1CreditsL.Caption = Nz(DLookup("[Sem1-Credits]", "Programme", "[ProgrammeID] = " & AMButton & ""))
```